# Control HP Proliant DL160 G6 fans from Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hp, hp-proliant

What software needs to be installed to allow proper control or management of the fans/BMC etc on a DL160 Gen 6? I have tried to find SPP/SUM but I don't have entitlement as the server is from 2010. Surely there is legacy drivers/firmware that can be installed?

We have installed a second CPU but struggling to understand why the CPU is running at ~90 degrees C and yet the fan RPM does not seem to be increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Please install the HPE Management Agents for your server. The specific [HP health agents you need are here](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=3884345&swItemId=MTX_7654fa5dc8824f4da7977d72c7&swEnvOid=4064).

All of the relevant software for your server model is [located here](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=3884345&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4064).

Comment: I've installed the HPE Management Agent, the WBEM Agents and SNMP server. I still see no obvious way to adjust fan speed. I have also installed the System Management Homepage, which just seems to be a dashboard of server information. What should I do next?

Comment: Nothing. Your server is going to run as it sees fit. The HP Management Agents are there to provide information reported from the hardware back to the OS. If the server isn't complaining, you shouldn't be worried.